# Elasticsearch data denormalization, JDBC Driver

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, elasticsearch

I'll better kick off with what I got now:

I've got around 50,000 documents in SQL Server that do not change that often and I import only new/updated data
Data looks pretty much like that

```
ReportID    DocumentID  DocumentTypeID  Title
137132      1           60              My Document Title
```

Now there's permission table, which looks like that:

```
DocumentID  DocumentTypeID  UserID
1           60              1916
1           60              1982
1           60              2055
1           60              2062
1           60              2063
```

When I import documents, i use ReportID as _id and concatenation of DocumentID and its Type as _parent field:

```
{
  "_id" : "137132",
  "_parent" : "D1T60",
  "Title" : "My Document Title"
}
```

then i have another type, which contains permissions and looks like this :

```
{
  "_id" : "D1T60",
  "UserID" : ["1916", "1982", "2055", "2062", "2063"]
}
```

So now it's quite easy to check if user has access to specific document, however the issue is, permissions table has around 70 million rows and each document has around 2000 users mapped to it. If if there's a new user, who will be able to access all new documents, river will have to reimport whole table, which is not efficient.

Anyone can point me to right direction on how to do it properly?

Thank you.

Comment: Ideally you'd have **roles** - each document is associated with one or more roles (and the roles themselves generally shouldn't change). You then assign one or more roles to the user. In your current model I can't see a way round needing to update all documents whenever a user joins or leaves your organisation.

Comment: This can be sorted out, however I cannot think on how I would map many-to-many relationship in elasticsearch. That would be efficient, however.

Comment: In my environment we store user details (including roles) in a relational database.  The roles are assigned to each document as an array (similar to how you have userID currently assigned). When a user runs a query the application filters the results by the roles that they have assigned - so the many-to-many relationship is just an array of roles on the document.

Comment: So you have to query first which roles user has and then filter out results by user roles, is that right? Can't this be done using one query? Or I misunderstood something :)

Comment: When a user logs into the portal / application the application will get their preferences from the RDMS. Part of this process is the extraction of the roles that have been assigned to a user - the application then uses this information to generate a filter  of what the user can see.

Comment: I guess there's no way to have user roles imported aswell and then pass only UserID?